# Read all nodes in a XML file

Tags: xml, pugixml

I have an XML file which looks like following:

```
<Employee>  
    <AddressDetails>
        <Street>ABC</Street>
        <City>XYZ</City>
        <Country>KLM</Country>
    </AddressDetails>

    <EmployeeName>LMNOP</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>

    <FamilyDetails>
        <Status>single</Status>
        <Children>0</Children>
    </FamilyDetails>
</Employee>
```

I want to read the values of all the nodes and store the node name and its value in two strings. I can read all the nodes under the root node `AddressDetails` with the following code. But how do I read all the nodes of `Employee`.

```
xml_node root_node = doc.child("Employee");
xml_node Address_node = root_node.child(AddressDetails);

    for(xml_node child = Address_node.first_child(); child; child = child.next_sibling())
    {
        std::string NodeName = child.name();
        std:string NodeValue = child.text().as_string();
    }
```

Comment: Use XPath to select `".//*"` and iterate the result.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain a little more...I didn't get how to do it